# Isekai Manga where MC is isekaied with other guys, but they are evil

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I can't really remember when I read this, but it was about an MC who got isekaied together with 2-4 other guys. But they were evil and the MC didn't travel together with them, don't remember the exact reason.

What I remember is that at the end of one of the latest chapters I read back then, the evil isekaied guys were conquering other nations and had just captured the ogre kingdom and raped its princess, if I remember correctly.
Would be nice if somebody could help out with this.

Comment: The first paragraph sounds like it could be a vague memory of Rising of the Shield Hero (of you replace evil with incompetence), but the second paragraph does not, unless it changed a lot after I stopped reading.

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: I think I read this 3 or 4 years ago, but i´m not entierly sure about that. And concerning the Shield Hero part, i would have to read it again to be sure, but i am also fairly certain that it wasn´t that Manga. @ArcanistLupus

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Genkai Level 1 kara no Nariagari: Saijaku Level no Ore ga Isekai Saikyou ni Naru made](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/genkai-level-1-kara-no-nariagari-saijaku-level-no-ore-ga-isekai-saikyou-ni-naru-made)*

> Takahashi Tetsuya was suddenly summoned to another world while on the way back from work. However, Tetsuya was only caught in the Hero’s summoning and his level cap was the lowest at 1. In this world, a low level cap indicated that one was weak and would not survive! To add on to his despair, he was thrown into a valley where a large amount of monsters lived. At the brink of being killed, he gained the unique skills, “Assimilate Corpse”, allowing him to gain the skills of the dead bodies he touched!

The MC is summoned alongside 3 other men and a girl he had just rescued. But because of his low level, he is immediately thrown away and left to die. The men, at least, are quite evil; they barely appear at the start but laugh at him being thrown away, but after he escapes the valley he learns that they've started conquering nearby areas.

The ogre rape scene is in Chapter 9.